# Como ler números separados por hífen num arquivo de texto?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Digamos que eu tenho um arquivo de texto onde a configuração dele é:

```
1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15-16-17-18-19-20...-999
```

Como faço pra ler o arquivo e ir salvando cada número desse que está está separado pelo `-`?

Comment: Você chegou a tentar algo? Qual foi a dificuldade encontrada?

Comment: Você pode ler a linha como texto e depois utilizar a função `split("-")`

Comment: Não cheguei. Na verdade nunca usei o Python! Mas cheguei nessa solução do split. Vou ler o arquivo como texto, depois dou split na string! Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 5):

Se existir a possibilidade de o arquivo possuir múltiplas linhas, você pode criar o seguinte gerador:

```
def read(filename):
    with open(filename) as stream:
        for line in stream:
            yield map(int, line.split('-'))
```

Ele recebe como parâmetro o nome do arquivo, abre-o e o lê linha a linha. Para cada linha, os números são separados pelo caractere hífen e convertidos para inteiro, retornando a lista resultante. Assim, para percorrer todos os números de um arquivo, basta fazer:

```
for numbers in read('numbers.txt'):
    for number in numbers:
        print(number)
```

O primeiro `for` percorre todas as linhas do arquivo e o segundo todos os números de cada linha.

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/BigPreciousCassowary)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Utilize o código:

```
arquivo = open('teste.txt', 'r')

for linha in arquivo:
    conteudo = linha.split('-')

print(conteudo)
```