# Como ler números separados por vírgula num arquivo de texto?

Tags: python

Olá,pessoal!.

Seguinte,eu tenho ***um arquivo*** em que tenho vários ***valores separados por vírgulas***.Eu preciso transformar esses *valores numa **lista***,e até ai é tranquilo.A questão é que usando o ***método split do Python*** pra separar pelas vírgulas,ele me retorna ***uma lista em que cada valor passar a ser uma string com aspas simples*** e,dessa forma,eu acabo não conseguindo fazer o que preciso fazer.
Por exemplo:

tenho no meu arquivo uma linha assim:

0,1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,9

ai eu separo pelo split e fica assim:

['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']

Alguém sabe como posso fazer pra retornar de vez inteiros **sem as aspas ?**

**Obrigado pela ajuda!**

Comment: Eu já respondi esse problema em [Como ler números separados por hífen num arquivo de texto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/257745/5878), basta você adaptar de hífen para vírgula.