# Como eliminar listas vazias na minha lista de listas?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Possuo o seguinte arquivo txt:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

2 3 4 5 6 7 6 8 9
3 4 5 6 7 7 8 8 9

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11

5 6 7 6  7 8 8 9 15
```

ao abri-lo e gerar uma lista de listas muitas posições ficam vazias, para tentar resolver esse problema eu usei o seguinte codigo:

```
with open('C:/Anaconda/loto.txt', 'r') as f: 
   results = [[int(entry) for entry in line.split() != []] for line in f.readlines()] 
   print(results)
```

e esta dando esse erro:

> ----> 2 results = [[int(entry) for entry in line.split() != []] for line in f.readlines()]

Alguém saberia me dizer como resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Esta linha aqui tem um problema:

```
   results = [[int(entry) for entry in line.split() != []] for line in f.readlines()] 
#                                                  ^-- falta um IF
```

Quando você usa o `for` condicionalmente, deve usar o formato

`for` **nome** `in` **lista** `if` **condição**

Que no seu caso, deveria ser algo como:

```
   results = [[int(entry) for entry in line.split() if entry != []] for line ... etc
```

Assim, quando `entry` for vazio, não vai ser adicionado na lista interna de `results`

Aproveitando, pode por uma condição na lista de fora, para filtrar linhas vazias se quiser:

```
   results = [...  igual linha de cima ...] for line in f.readlines() if line.split()]
```

Aqui, o `line.split()` vai ser considerado verdadeiro se não forem linhas em branco.

Se estiver com um pouco de dificuldade de entender as peculiaridades do Py, aqui tem uma alternativa menos críptica do código, que pode ser facilmente adaptada para listas:

> [Como ler números separados por hífen num arquivo de texto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/257745/70)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta e pelas dicas.

Answer (score 3):

A resposta do Bacco explica bem qual foi o problema, mas gostaria de adicionar alguns comentários.

A função `readlines` irá ler todo o conteúdo do arquivo de uma só vez, colocando cada linha do arquivo em um item de uma lista. Para arquivos pequenos - e para aplicações que esbanjam memória - isso não será um problema, mas caso necessite processar arquivos muito grandes, será um problema. Uma forma de contornar isso é utilizando geradores. É possível trabalhar com cada linha do arquivo separadamente, lendo uma a uma e fazendo o processamento necessário. Para definir um gerador, basta utilizar o `yield`:

```
def list_of_integers(filename):
    with open(filename) as stream:
        for line in stream:
            line = line.strip()
            if line:
                yield [int(number) for number in line.split()]
```

Assim, você poderá percorrer todas as linhas da seguinte forma:

```
for numbers in list_of_integers('C:/Anaconda/loto.txt'):
    print(numbers)
```

O resultado seria:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 8, 9]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
[5, 6, 7, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 15]
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/ForcefulUprightAddresses)</sup>

Outros comentários:

- Ao abrir o arquivo somente para leitura, você pode omitir o argumento de modo, `'r'`;
- Evite variáveis com nome `f`, pois não serão legíveis no decorrer do código;
- Se as linhas do arquivo forem muito grandes também, convém retornar um gerador de geradores substituindo os colchetes em `yield` por parenteses. Desta forma, a linha ficará em memória apenas uma vez e não duas - mesmo que por um curto período de tempo;
- A função `strip` se faz necessária pois, nesse caso, o caractere `\n` é mantido em `line`;